# Returning a non-unit value from a scala while loop

Tags: scala

```
private def canProceed: Boolean = {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis
    val endTime = startTime + (5 * 1000)

    while (System.currentTimeMillis < endTime) {
      if (isSafe) { // method where my current implementation is just true or false for testing
        true
      } else {
        println("Not safe. Trying again")
      }
    }
    false
}
```

This will just keep iterating through the while loop since the `true` from the conditional doesn't actually do anything as a scala while loop always returns a Unit, so the final result will always be `false`. Is there some idiomatic way to do this without leveraging `var` or `return`?

Comment: You can, of course, use the `return` keyword. It's usually not preferred, but it seems like the easiest thing to do here.

Comment: I'm aware I can use ```var``` or ```return```, but there must be a cleaner way to do this. I try to avoid using ```return``` in Scala. I'll add this to the original question

Comment: You say you want to try and run something for 5 seconds... this is regardless of how many times this thing actually runs in 5 seconds? Also little note: however fast this code goes, `startTime` and the `System.currentTimeMillis` inside the `while` condition will be different numbers.

Comment: It's an arbitrary threshold and something I can tweak later. I'll remove that information from my question as it's irrelevant to my problem

Comment: Let's see if I got this right: whatever you're doing inside the while loop can be a function returning a boolean value... (`def f: Boolean = ...`) and then you do `if (System.currentTimeMillis < endTime) { f } else { false }` and get rid of the returning `false`

Comment: Seems like you are trying to implement `Await.result` for test purposes. Why not just using `Await.result`?

Answer (score 0):

Well technically speaking you could write your own tail-recursive function like this following.

```scala
def attemptWhile(cond: => Boolean)(check: => Boolean): Boolean = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(): Boolean = {
    if (cond) check || loop()
    else false 
  }
  
  loop()
}
```

Which then you could use like:

```scala
private def canProceed: Boolean = {
  val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis
  val endTime = startTime + (5 * 1000)

  attemptWhile(System.currentTimeMillis < endTime)(isSafe)
}
```

However, this is still depending on mutable state so not really functional.
At that point, you may wonder if it is worth the effort adding that `attemptWhile` or just use `return`.

---

BTW, if you want a fully functional solution this seems something that could be solved using something like **fs2** but maybe that is just too off-topic for you.

Comment: Using `{}` makes it more like a `while`: `attemptWhile(...){ isSafe }`

Answer (score -1):

You are basically asking whether or not you can do *anything* that's not a side effect inside a while loop and observe it on the outside.

Just like you *cannot* do anything worthwhile **without** side-effects in a while loop, you **cannot** observe anything on the outside of a while loop without side effects. The **var** and **return** keywords are directly related to side effects.

(Of course you can observe the heating up of your CPU or the slowdown of your program, but this is usually disregarded as it doesn't pertain to computation directly)

**edit**

For yield is there to address exactly this "problem".

```
scala> for {
     |  x <- List(1,2,3)
     |  y <- List(4,5,6)
     | } yield (x,y)
val res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6), (3,4), (3,5), (3,6))
```

You may want to look into effect types (Cats effect, Zio). They deal with exactly the case of turning effects into values. In your case, there are 2 effects:

1. `System.currentTimeMillis`  this value is mutable and changes *over time*
2. `isSafe`  has to be mutable and changed from the outside.

**edit2**

Here's an example of how you can iterate a side effect with Cats Effect

```
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp}
import cats.implicits.catsSyntaxMonad

import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

object CheckTime extends IOApp {

  val checkTime: IO[Long] = IO.delay { System.currentTimeMillis() }

  val waitForSomeTime: IO[Long] = for {
    start    <- checkTime
    _        <- IO.delay { println(s"Start time: $start") }
    stopTime <- checkTime.iterateWhile(currentTime => currentTime - start < 10.seconds.toMillis)
    _        <- IO.delay { println(s"Ended at $stopTime") }
  } yield stopTime

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = waitForSomeTime.as(ExitCode.Success)
  
}
```

Output:

```
Start time: 1608103950673
Ended at 1608103960673
```